# PHP-FPM runs PHP scripts as root

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm

I have a web server setup using nginx and PHP-FPM listening on a Unix socket.
In my php-fpm.conf, I have specified

```
user = www
group = www
```

When I run *ps aux*, I can see that the php-fpm worker processes run as www; the php-fpm master process runs as root.

However, I noticed that PHP scripts are executed as root; at least that's the output of

```
echo get_current_user();
```

What can I do to run scripts as the www user? How can this even happen if the worker processes run as www?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[get_current_user()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-current-user.php) returns the current owner of the script, not the user executing it. To get the current user executing the script try `exec('whoami');` or

```
$user = posix_getpwuid(posix_getuid());
echo $user['name'];
```

Comment: Ok... executing the commands above shows the right user (www). Now I only have to find out why I get safe mode warnings saying the script is executed as uid 0.. thanks for correcting my mistake!